# when importing a model with a rig from the asset browser, the rig stops working

Tags: rigging, import, asset-browser

when I tried to add a model from the browser asset, the rig stopped working for her. Then I changed
[image]        import mode from append to link , but it didn't help. how do I make everything work correctly?